# Set value knowing the EObject and its EAttribute

Tags: java, eclipse, emf

I want to set the value of an object `EObject` knowing it's `EAttribute`. Is that possible?

I can use reflections, build the method name and invoke it, but is there a better way to achieve that? Maybe some EMF Util classes?

```
public static Object invokeMethodBy(EObject object, EAttribute attribute, Object...inputParameters){
    String attrName = attribute.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + attribute.getName().substring(1);
    Object returnValue = null;
    try {
        returnValue = object.getClass().getMethod("set"+attrName, boolean.class).invoke(object,inputParameters);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
            | SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EMF has already its own introspection mechanisms, that do not use Java Reflection but use static generated code.

What you need is this:

```
object.eSet(attribute, value);
```

If the attribute is a "many" relationship, such as a `List`, you need to retrieve the list before and then add the content to the list:

```
if (attribute.isMany()) {
    List<Object> list = (List<Object>) object.eGet(attribute);
    list.addAll(value);
}
```

In case you don't have the `EAttribute` but have the name of the attribute (as `String`) you can also retrieve the `EStructuralFeature` by name using the `EClass` metadata:

```
EStructuralFeature feature = object.eClass.getEStructuralFeature(attributeName);
object.eSet(feature, value);
```

You should look to the EObject API, in special the methods starting by "e". `EcoreUtil` class has also useful methods.